# apache 2.2.22 mod_rewrite RewriteCond, how to set the regexp

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Sorry, my initial description was to short.

What I need to do is, to do two redirects on one base-url with two different conditions.
First is to redirect a request with just the base-url (like _http://some_url.org) to _http://some_other_url.org .

```
_http://some_url.org -> _http://some_other_url.org
```

The second one is, if _http://some_url.org/some_subdir is requested it shoud be redirected to SSL of the same host _https://some_url.org/some_subdir .
So in case 2 it should not be redirected to some_other_url.org .

```
_http://some_url.org/some_subdir -> https_://some_url.org/some_subdir
```

Both rewrites are not verry complex for its own, but I can't get them working together.
So my problem is, how do I have to set the RewriteCond (to be exact the regexp) to do the matching. The http->https overrules always.

I did several experiments with RewriteCond, RewriteRule, RedirectMatch but I didn't get it. Does anybody have an idea?

Oh, btw this should be done by the vhost-config, not with .htaccess-files in document-folders. It's a restriction I'm not responsible for :-( cause developers sometimes empty the doc-folders.

Sorry, I had to do this `_http` because of this editor to not recognize this "URLs".
thanks a lot

best regards, M.

Comment: `Redirect` is enough for this. If you’re “stuck”, either read the docs (again), or give us a _real_ problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, thanks to Jim from google-groups

```
 RewriteRule ^/$        http://some_other_url.org [R=permanent,L,NS]    

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]  
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://some_url.org/$1 [R=permanent,L,NS]
```

PERFECT! Thanks a lot Jim.
This exactly solves my Problem.

Best regards, M.